# CDF of sum of variables given inequality on random variable

Tags: probability

[image]

**Correct Answer : 1/54**

Solution based on answerers!: Let $N_1, N_2$ denote number of claims in two consecutive months.

$P(N_1+N_2> 3 | N_1 \leq 1)$

$ = 1-P(N_1+N_2\leq 3|N_1\leq 1) $

$ = 1- \frac{P(N_1+N_2\leq 3, N_1 =0)+P(N_1+N_2\leq 3, N_1= 1)}{P(N\leq 1)}$
$ = 1- \frac{P(N_2\leq 3, N_1 =0)+P(N_2\leq 2, N_1= 1)}{P(N\leq 1)}$

by independence, $= 1- \frac{P(N_2\leq 3)P(N_1 =0)+P(N_2\leq 2)P(N_1= 1)}{P(N\leq 1)}$ = .0185 = 1/54

Comment: Remark: "more than three" corresponds with $N_1+N_2\geq4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(N_1+N_2\le 3| N_1\le 1)=\frac{P(N_1+N_2\le3, N\le 1)}{P(N_1\le 1)}$$ the numerator can be calculated as $$ P(N_1+N_2 \le3, N_1=0) + P(N_1+N_2 \le3, N_1=1)$$ since $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent $$ P(N_1+N_2\le 3, N_1=0) = P(N_2\le 3) P(N_1=0) $$ the other term can be calculated similarly.

Comment: Caution: In the problem statement I read "more than three". So it asks for the probability $P(N_1+N_2>3\mid N_1\leq1)$.

Comment: why can apply independence to $P(N_1+N_2\leq3, N_1=0)$ it is a function of both $N_1, N_2$? why or why not is it equivalent to $P(N_2 \leq 3)$ if you plug in $N_1 = 0$??

Comment: because $\{ N_1+N_2 \leq 3, N_1=0\} = \{ N_1\leq 3, N_1=0 \}$

Comment: @drhab: yes thanks, corrected that in my answer.

Comment: @MinYoungKim Do you agree that $\{N_1+N_2\leq3,N_1=0\}=\{N_2\leq 3,N_1=0\}$? Consequently $P(\{N_1+N_2\leq3,N_1=0\})=P(\{N_2\leq 3,N_1=0\})$ and the RHS of this equals $P(N_2\leq3)P(N_1=0)$ because $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent. Mick was also trying to say that but made a typo in his comment. He wrote $\{N_1+N_2\leq3,N_1=0\}=\{N_1\leq3,N_1=0\}$ which is wrong, but it is beyond doubt that he meant to write $\{N_1+N_2\leq3,N_1=0\}=\{N_2\leq3,N_1=0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that $P(A|B\cup C)=P(A|B)+P(A|C)$ for mutually exclusive events $B$ and $C$.

The correct formula is $P(A|B \cup C)=tP(A|B)+(1-t)P(A|C)$ where $t=\frac {P(B)} {P(B)+P(C)}$.

Comment: so How would I go about modifying the expression to calculate answer?

Comment: @MinYoungKim I have given   the formula. Now you  should be able to compute the probability.